# Excel found unreadable content in ".xls". while export crystal report to excel

Tags: excel, crystal-reports, export

I am  Exporting  the Data From the Crystal reports to the PDF its working fine 
and showing all the Records but when I Export it in Excel File Exported Successfully and when I Open it in  Excel given an error message--
**File Error :data may have been lost**

When I click on OK button 
' In Excel file the Header is not Visible of Column '

here the header in the Crystal report coming from the Database .

any help would be great appreciated.

Rajesh

Comment: It might be more of an Excel issue than a Crystal Reports.  You might be exporting beyond the limits of Excel or there might be something in your [data](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/8fcd399f-5f8e-4819-b49f-c1cf9ebd0db7/) that's causing it.  Do you have data on your Excel sheet?  Do you have the same number of rows?  Try exporting a small set and without any numbers.  Just to see if it's that report or a constant export error.