# Crystal Report 7.0 add Excel 14.0 to Export Type

Tags: excel, crystal-reports, export

I wanted to export a Crystal Report 7.0 to Excel 14.0 (Excel 2010)?

The problem I am facing is Exporting a Report to Excel 8.0 opens on any Windows XP system but not on Windows 7. The system on which Windows 7 present has Office 2010.

Here is the [unsolved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286615/excel-found-unreadable-content-in-xls-while-export-crystal-report-to-excel) asked earlier.

I want a solution or workaround which can be adopted on enterprise level means around 2000 systems may affect for this.

Comment: perhaps an upgrade? *Seagate* Crystal Reports 7 was released in 1999

Comment: That I can't, because there are thousands of reports will get affected and also some 50-60 modules need to recompile for version enhancement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overcome the problem which I was facing.

I was having `U2FXLS.DLL` in `C:\WINDOWS\Crystal` directory with `Version 7.0.0.50`. As per my question my problem was a `.xls` file exported from  `Crystal Report` is opening in `Windows XP + Office 2010` machine and not in `Windows 7 + Office 2010`, so I thought If newer version of DLL present then it may solve my problem and searched the same DLL.

I got DLL with `Version 8.6.0.279` [here](http://www.topdll.com/download/u2fxls.dll?q=4a5cc0355945edf529ae89bc367c717a).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a solution, which can be applied on Crystal reports level.

A workaround is to use a viewer like this one:
http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/default.aspx

It can export the report to Excel 2007-2010 directly or using an extension. Here is a video about the options available when the extension is used:
http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/Preview.aspx (check the video at the bottom of the page - Advanced export to Excel from Crystal Reports and SQL Ad-hoc reports)

If you cannot use the viewer you can consider to schedule the report and deliver it by e-mail.